# FPDF table cell padding

Tags: fpdf

I have created table using cells in FPDF..But Im not able to give padding for the cells and the text starts exactly near to the margin.How can we give a padding space at the beginning of the text.

I have attached the code here

```
    $w = array(90, 20, 20, 12, 20);
    for($i=0;$i<count($header);$i++)
    {
            $this->Cell($w[$i],7,$header[$i],1,0,'L',true);     
    }
```

The output is as below

[image]

BUt I want it to be disaplyed with left padding as below

[image]

Comment: Have you tried [SetMargins](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/setmargins.htm)?

Comment: @gonutz Yes..Did not work out

Comment: Can I ask where you entered the setMargins function? it is possible that from the position does not give you the desired result. maybe you could try with setLeftMargin inserting something like: "$ pdf-> SetLeftMargin(20); // 2cm". I did a test first and I had no problems. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Try this ... $this->Cell($w[$i],7,'  '.$header[$i],1,0,'L',true);

Answer (score 3):

The FPDF Class has a protected property for cell margin:

```
protected $cMargin;            // cell margin
```

I'm not certain if the addition of this property post-dates the original post of this question, but it's available in Version: 1.83. However, there is no method to set this value, so it may be best to extend the class and add your own. For example:

```
class MyFPDF extends FPDF
{
    function SetCellMargin($margin) { $this->cMargin = $margin; }
}
```

Change the class name "MyFPDF" to whatever you wish. You'll need to construct the PDF using this class name instead of "FPDF" and set the value to what you wish:

```
$pdf = new MyFPDF();
$pdf->SetCellMargin(4);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$this -> Cell(80);`

// Move to 8 cm to the right and the below cell follow on the same line

`$this -> Cell($w[$i], 7, $header[$i], 1, 0, 'L', true);`

Answer (score 0):

I have done it by adding more space in string. For example, '......  .. . . . . . .Stock Code' (replace '.' with space).

It is a hardcore way, but it works for me.